# Adding condition in ComponentDidMount to display chart data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I've added a condition in componentDidMount to showcase data for either 1 or 2 datasets based on the pros recieved. However, I'm getting an error in the if condition. Here is BarChart component. Inside it, I've already imported Chart from 'chart.js'.

```
class BarChart1 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
chartRef = React.createRef();

componentDidMount() {
    const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");
    let dataCheck = null;
    if(this.props.data2){
        let dataCheck = {
            labels: this.props.labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: this.props.label1,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(26,179,148,0.5)',
                    borderColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.7)",
                    data: this.props.data1
                }, {
                    label: this.props.label2,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5)',
                    pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                    data: this.props.data2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    else {
        let dataCheck = {
            labels: this.props.labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: this.props.label1,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(26,179,148,0.5)',
                    borderColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.7)",
                    data: this.props.data1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    new Chart(myChartRef, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {dataCheck},
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: true,
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    gridlines: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 9
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        plugins: [{
            beforeInit: function(chart) {
               chart.data.labels.forEach(function(e, i, a) {
                  if (/\n/.test(e)) {
                     a[i] = e.split(/\n/);
                  }
               });
            }
     }]
    })
}

render() {
    return <canvas ref={this.chartRef} />
}

}
```

I've edited my question. I'm now getting a blank chart without the error.

[image]

Comment: thats probably because you dont provide it any data, try to log the dataCheck var and see what its filled with

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code.

1. Your have to end the variable declaration with ; instead of ,
2. You have to declare datacheck outside the if else block unless you want it undefined

```js
    componentDidMount() {
                ...
                let dataCheck;
                if(this.props.data2){
                     dataCheck = {
                       ...
                    }
                }
                else {
                    dataCheck = {
                      ...
                    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you code it out please because I didn't understand it propely. Thanks! Also, even after removing the comma or even adding a semicolon, I get the error that 'dataCheck' is not defined.

Comment: Ok, so I removed that comma and added a new code above the if condition: let dataCheck = null; but I'm getting a blank chart without the error.